# Flutter: SizedBox with Dynamic Height

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a custom list (alternative to using `ListTile` widget).

My code looks like this:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
    child: SizedBox(
      height: 70,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          thumbnail,
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0),
              child: CommentDescription(
                author: author,
                comment: comment,
                createdAt: createdAt,
                isLiked: isLiked,
                likesCount: likesCount,
              )
            )
          ),
          menu
        ],
      )
    )
  );
}
```

CommentDescription Widget

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$author',
              maxLines: 1,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0)),
            Text('$comment')
          ],
        )
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                '$createdAt',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0,
                  color: Colors.grey
                )
              )
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () => print('liking comment'),
              icon: Icon(
                isLiked ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 16.0
              )
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                '$likesCount',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 12.0
                )
              )
            )
          ],
        )
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

The problem I have is that, the code is using `SizedBox` widget to wrap each tile, which requires a fixed height. But I want something that can work with dynamic height because the height of the content cannot be predetermined. Please how do I approach this.

Note: When I remove `SizedBox` widget, i get this error message in the console:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout(): RenderFlex children
have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded. When a column
is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if 
it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along 
the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates 
that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical 
direction. These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to
shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent. 
Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits 
for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow 
the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining 
space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex 
to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints 
provided by the parent.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply remove all the Expanded widget in CommentDescription. Expanded can be used only when the width or height of the parent Row or Column is fixed.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            '$author',
            maxLines: 1,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0)),
          Text('$comment')
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
            child: Text(
              '$createdAt',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.0,
                color: Colors.grey
              )
            )
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () => print('liking comment'),
            icon: Icon(
              isLiked ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
              color: Colors.red,
              size: 16.0
            )
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
            child: Text(
              '$likesCount',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontSize: 12.0
              )
            )
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. You said 'Expanded can only be used when the height of the parent Column or Row is fixed'. But in the first widget, Expanded is being used in a Row without any fixed height and it's still working. Can you explain why?

Comment: @IsraelObanijesu Sorry, I made a mistake in the description. For Row widget, the width has to be fixed. For Column, the height has to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Just use shrink Wrap=true in list property and wrap with container , sizeBox Heigth and Width will be auto adjusted

```
Container(child:ListView.separated(
itemCount:1
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    return Container();
}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to limit the size of the thumbnail. If this is the case, try this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 70,
            child: thumbnail,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0),
              child: CommentDescription(
                author: author,
                comment: comment,
                createdAt: createdAt,
                isLiked: isLiked,
                likesCount: likesCount,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          menu
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: hi there, i see that you don't understand my question or what im trying to achieve. This is how the code looks like in the app: https://imgur.com/hHrul8k As shown in that image, the last comment is having an overflow problem because the length is bigger than the sized box height, so i am trying to handle it dynamically. The thumbnail size is fine. Also, i think your code won't work 'cause i tried removing SizedBox earlier and it throws an error, so i think Expanded needs some sort of boundary

Comment: @IsraelObanijesu You don't need to set a fixed height for children of ListView. Please try my code and if you get an error, let me know what error you get.

Comment: @IsraelObanijesu what error did you get? The problem is probably in the CommentDescription widget.

Comment: Yeah, this question needs more details, i will provide the code of the ```CommentDescription``` widget right now, flutter is giving me some descriptive error message which i think you might be able to understand.....i will edit the post right now